# Renaming a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

How can I rename a project in vb? Its initial name was WindowsApplication1 and then I changed it in solution explorer, but in the upper left corner the name is WindowsApplication1 - Microsoft Visual Studio. I've also changed the root namespace, but what is shown next to - Microsoft Visual Studio is the same:(.

Comment: Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window and select Rename.  Click around some more, this is supposed to be easily discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the project with a text editor like notepad and search and replace  WindowsApplication1 with any name.

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2013 and most likely earlier versions.  These names are set in Project / WindowsApplication1 Project Properties / Application.  You can change the Assembly name (which is what appears in the top left corner).  You can change the Root namespace; tool tips show this name space for public items in your project.